# Run imageMagick command with Nodejs

Tags: node.js, imagemagick

I am trying to improve the quality of a scanned PDF to proceed to OCR. I found the command textcleaner that uses ImageMagick. So how can I include this :
 `textcleaner -g -e normalize -f 30 -o 12 -s 2 original.jpg output.jpg` 
  in my Nodejs code ?

Comment: Is `exec` maybe something for you https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `exec`:

```
exec(`textcleaner -g -e normalize -f 30 -o 12 -s 2 ${inputName} ${outputName}`);
```

or use a [child process](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html)

```
const { spawn } = require('child_process');
const textcleaner = spawn('textcleaner', ['-g', '-e', 'normalize', '-f 30', '-o 12', '-s 2', inputName, outputName]);

textcleaner.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
  console.log(`stdout: ${data}`);
});
```

Comment: First of all thank u but when i try your second code i get this error : Error: spawn textcleaner ENOENT . where is the problem in spawn or textcleaner ?

Comment: hi, seems your pass an invalid file path, change `inputName `